# While installing pdfkit throug npm install it is throwing Error "could not resolve 'fs' module"

Tags: module, npm, fs, pdfkit

I tried installing the **Npm module** named '**pdfkit**'. it is getting installed and is showing in the node_modules folder also. But when i try importing the module by :

```
var pdfkit=require ('pdfkit');
```

then npm throws an error stating that could not resolve fs module.

It is working fine in other already installed modules in the project.

**Npm version:-** 3.3.12

**Node v:**- 5.4.0

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to install the "node-fs" module (npm install node-fs)

Otherwise, the location of the module folder may be the cause.

I just solved a similar problem on win8.

When installing pdfkit as described in the manual (npm install pdfkit), the modules got placed in a folder named "node_modules" **in the current directory** of the cmd line program.

In my case, this was "C:\Users\User\node_modules".

A simple "dir node_modules" command reveals the installed modules:

"file_saver", "node-fs", pdfkit", "requirejs".

My problem was that the "require 'pdf' node statement throws a "**module not found** error" when the script is in a folder which is not in the path of C:\Users.

In my case, the path of the script is "C:\somefolder\somefile.js".

To solve the problem, I installed a second set of node modules, this time in the "C:\" folder.

```
cd C:\

npm install pdfkit

npm install file-saver

npm install node-fs

npm install requirejs
```

And voila: now it works.

A simple "dir C:\node_modules" command reveals the modules in the new location.